# Plotting a function defined by equation without closed form solution

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to have the a silimiar plot to the one Wolfram Alpha provides me [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B24.6347%20(246.347%20x%20%2B%20sqrt((246.347%20x%20%2B%2020)%5E2%20%2B%201)%20%2B%2020)%5E(-a)%20%3D%2030.2879%20(-33.6532%20x%20%2B%20sqrt(x%20(1132.54%20x%20-%2020191.9)%20%2B%2090001)%20%2B%20300)%5E(-a),%20a%3E0%7D) to the equation

$24.6347 \left(246.347 x + \sqrt{(246.347 x + 20)^2 + 1} + 20\right)^{-a} =\ 30.2879 \left(-33.6532 x + \sqrt{x (1132.54 x - 20191.9) + 90001} + 300\right)^{-a}$

for $a>0$. This equation however has no closed form solution for x in terms of a so I don't know how to achieve such a plot.

Minimal "Working" Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}


\begin{axis}[xlabel=a ,
    ylabel = x,
     xmin=0, xmax=10,
    ymin=0,ymax=1]
  \addplot [
    domain=0:10, 
    samples=500, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {24.6347*(246.347*x+sqrt((246.347*x+20)^2+1)+20)^(-a)=30.2879*(-33.6532*x+ sqrt(x*(1132.54*x-20191.9)+90001)+300)^(-a)}; 
%switched the variables because gnuplot requires the variable x as input as far as i know
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot really produce implicit plots but you can produce contour plots, which have the same information. So instead of plotting the solutions of `A=B` one plots the contours of `A-B=0`. You need to run with `-shell-escape` since this needs `gnuplot` (which your above example didn't need).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90},ylabel=$a$,
    xlabel=$x$,xmin=0, xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1]
    \addplot3 [contour gnuplot={levels=0,labels=false},
        domain=0:1,domain y=0:1] 
        {24.6347*(246.347*x+sqrt((246.347*x+20)^2+1)+20)^(-y)
    -30.2879*(-33.6532*x+ sqrt(x*(1132.54*x-20191.9)+90001)+300)^(-y)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to reproduce the Wolfram alpha plot you need to switch `x` and `y` back, and adjust the domains.

Comment: This is not working for me. I get the error message ..._contourtmp0.table could not be opened. Normal gnuplots are working fine though.

Comment: Your example is now working (no idea what fixed it). How would I go about adding a straight line at a=0.8 in your example?

Comment: @PaulOstmann I do not know what caused your problems but the straight line is as easy as saying `\draw (0,0.8) -- (1,0.8);` inside the axis environment. (It is a bit of a cheat since these are technically 3d coordinates but works.)

Comment: I found another solution myself: I simply added another contour plot {y-1}(I initially said 0.8 because your solution has the standard domain with y<=1) but now im stuck on trying to add a third plot: the difference of the 2 functions by which I mean 1 - the function in my post. It's supposed to look like this: [imgur link](https://imgur.com/a/s1Cddsl)

Comment: @PaulOstmann With your function you mean the difference the contour plot is using? And yes, `\addplot` also works. Does ` \addplot3 [contour gnuplot={levels=0,labels=false},
        domain=0:1,domain y=0:1] 
        {1-24.6347*(246.347*x+sqrt((246.347*x+20)^2+1)+20)^(-y)
    +30.2879*(-33.6532*x+ sqrt(x*(1132.54*x-20191.9)+90001)+300)^(-y)};` work for you?

Comment: I had tried that before but that didn't give me the desired result. After some time I found the solution:  \addplot3 [contour gnuplot={levels=0,labels=false},
        domain=0:2,contour/draw color={green},domain y=0:1,samples = 70, samples y = 70] 
        {24.6347*(246.347*(1-y)+sqrt((246.347*(1-y)+20)^2+1)+20)^(-x)
    -30.2879*(-33.6532*(1-y)+ sqrt((1-y)*(1132.54*(1-y)-20191.9)+90001)+300)^(-x)};

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it does have a closed form solution, at least for *a* as a function of *x*.

[image: latex equations]

Comment: Honestly I'd prefer your solution. This is just a closed-form plot.

Answer (score 2):

run with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=0.75}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1)(20,6)
\psaxes[Dx=2]{->}(0,0)(-2,-0.5)(18,5)[$a$,0][$x$,90]
\rput[lb](0,0){%
  \pspicture*(0.1,0.1)(16,6)
  \psplotImp[algebraic,linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt](0.05,0.05)(20,6){
    24.6347*(246.347*y + sqrt((246.347*y + 20)^2 + 1) + 20)^(-x)- 
    30.2879*(-33.6532*y + sqrt(y*(1132.54*y - 20191.9) + 90001) + 300)^(-x)}
  \endpspicture}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]